# Is there a general equation for fundamental identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain with field of fractions $K$, let $L/K$ be a finite field extension and $A$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $L$.

Let $P$ be a nonzero prime ideal of $R$ and $Q_1,...,Q_n$ be nonzero distinct prime ideals of $A$ such that $PA=Q_1^{e_1}\cdots Q_n^{e_n}$. Let $f_i$ be the inertia degree of $Q_i$ over $P$ for each $i$.

If $L/K$ is separable in addition, then we have a fundamental identity $\sum_{i=1}^n e_if_i = [L:K]$.

Is there a general equation which holds even when $L/K$ is inseparable?

Comment: If your definition of inertia degree $f_i$ is $[A/Q_i:R/P]$, then separability plays no role. The above just uses the fact $\dim_{R/P} A/PA=[L:K]$.

Comment: @Mohan Yes, but I wonder if this equation holds for general finite extension if we replace $[L:K]$ by $[L:K]_s$.

Comment: I do not understand. Since you can only get $[L:K]$, separable or not, how do you get the separable degree?